# Ищу простую реализацию гибкого языка

Tags: любой-язык

Хочу найти экстремально простую и понятную реализацию (и желательно небольшую по объёму кода), пускай и тормозную для какого-нибудь простого динамического языка программирования.

Под такими языками я имею ввиду: Scheme, Tcl, Lua, может быть JavaScript (хотя не хотелось бы).

В первую очередь нужна простота и понятность.

Есть кандидаты?

Comment: А вам для чего? В принципе, несложно руками написать интерпретатор простого языка. (Хоть на lex/yacc.)

Comment: Для демонстрации другим людям в образовательных целях. Дабы показать как всё на самом деле просто, нет никакой магии.

Comment: Тогда может проще самому написать? Токенизатор пишется руками, парсер методом [рекурсивного спуска](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursive_descent_parser) хорошо описан у Вирта в "Алгоритмы + структуры данных = программы", а слабать execution engine вообще пара пустяков. Если все переменные сделать глобальными, будет совершенно нечего делать.

Comment: > а слабать execution engine вообще пара пустяков. (Если все переменные сделать глобальными, а функции без параметров, будет совершенно нечего делать, бейсик-бейсиком.)

Нет нужна реализация существующего, хорошо спроектированного языка.

Comment: о, хорошо, тут язык с тривиальным синтаксисом.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

http://howtowriteaprogram.blogspot.ru/2010/11/lisp-interpreter-in-90-lines-of-c.html вуаля. Лисп интерпретатор в 90 строк срр кода.

Answer (score 0):

> несложно руками написать интерпретатор простого языка
>
> слабать execution engine вообще пара пустяков

Покажите пожалуйста свою реализацию определения пользовательских функций, с их последующим вызовом, в рантайме. А то что-то все герои написания интерпретаторов (а фактически -- парсеров) на этом моменте сдуваются 8-)

Во вопросу -- нашел [PLAI @ Shriram Krishnamurthy](http://cs.brown.edu/courses/cs173/2012/book/), неспешно делаю [подстрочный перевод](https://github.com/ponyatov/PLAI). Реализации функций посвящена бОльшая часть всей книги, синтаксическому разбору -- два абзаца (раздел 2.1 и укладка выражения с систему типов диалекта DrRacket `plai-typed`). Ну и на закуску -- управление памятью со сборкой мусора, и что-то там про типизацию.

Comment: Что-то это больше на вопрос похоже, чем на ответ. Хотя я не уверен, так что тревогу не ставлю.

Comment: Ну вот вам, например: http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/452045/10105.

Comment: По обоим комментам ответ nil. (1) это бвл риторический ответ (2) пока не будет все же приведен пример - по ссылке нет вызова определенной ранее функуии или хотя бы рекурсии. Только вызов вкомпиленных в ядро (псевдо)функци

Comment: @DmitryPonyatov: Ну вы как бы должны понять, что пример год назад писался без учёта ваших пожеланий теперь. Ну а в чём вы видите проблему дополнить интерпретатор? Синтаксическое определение юзеровской функции? Кастомный activation record? Выполнять код по разобранной объектной структуре тот пример уже умеет.

Comment: Вы хотите динамически (как бы из eval) создаваемых функций? Если только статические (определяемые на момент парсинга исходника) интересны, то может глянуть, например, [сорсы awk](http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/gawk.git/tree/)

Comment: Там нет кода *динамической компиляции* syntax tree -> *installed_function, т.е. даже добавив в грамматику код, создающий из конструкции типа def user_fn(args) { blablabla } синтаксическое дерево, не предусмотрен способ получить из него нечто аналогичное <installed_function>*f_pause.

Comment: Да, динамической компиляции в awk нет. Ну, как писать в принципе ясно, а смотреть ... Может в лиспе? (например взять сорсы emacs-а). Или в Tcl тоже есть динамика (не помню)?

Comment: Т.е. нужно добавлять еще одну сущность -- пользовательскую функцию, определенную как синтаксическое дерево, и механизм подстановки ее тела в место вызова с заменой параметров, или другие реализации вызова (как раз на деталях реализации в PLAI сейчас остановился). Теоретически можно привлечь LLVM JIT, и использовать настоящую динамическую компиляцию, но я пока настолько глубоко не смотрел.

Comment: Можно попробовать другой крайне странный механизм -- заводить стек состояний лексера/парсера, запоминать точки определения функций в исходном коде (полностью загруженном в ОЗУ, чтобы не возиться с перемоткой файлов), при вызове функции сбрасывать в стек контекст парсера, и переключать лексер на определение функции, по ходу подставляя параметры. Живьем такого кода со "скАчками" по исходнику еще не видел.

Comment: Я бы всегда (и при начальном парсинге и динамически) компилировал функцию в некий байт-код с определенным для всех функций единообразным доступам к вектору аргументов переменной длины. Впрочем, это дело вкуса.

Comment: Вспомнил очень хорошую книжку -- "Языки программирования, разработка и реализация". Читал 100 лет назад, но она на  меня прроизвела больше воздействие. Не читали?

Comment: Пратт/Зелковиц показался крайне поверхностным, все никак не могу вспомнить, где я (кажется на русском) читал подробное описание по ручному синтезу конечных автоматов для парсера, наверно все же в Драконе. Облизывался на новое издание Дракона (с новым разделом управления памятью), но цена на ozonе взрывает жабу.

Comment: У Пратт/Зелковиц классно описана организация рантайма (распределение памяти, доступ к параметрам) для разных языков. А сам процесс компиляции, да, пожалуй упрощенно, на скорою руку.

Comment: @DmitryPonyatov: Ну да, нету. Но сваять это из существующего кода нет никакой проблемы. Выполнить готовое дерево код умеет, ну так научить его выполнять поддерево с явным activation record'ом пара пустяков. Осталось связать имя функции с поддеревом. Где конкретно вы видите сложность?

Comment: @DmitryPonyatov: В качестве иллюстрации набросал версию с локальными функциями и рекурсивным вызовом: https://github.com/vladd/SimpleParser2