# Выполнение программы из .ini

Tags: c++, синтаксический-анализ

Допустим мы в ini файл пишем вот это:

```
repeat (8)
{
click(10,10)
pause(100s)
click(10,10)
repeat(2)
   {
   pause(10)
   }
}
```

что то вроде кода самого обычного кликера, по типу UOpilot.

Как обрабатывать и анализировать циклы, вложенные циклы?

Comment: Ну, а в чём проблема? Вам нужно написать простой интерпретатор. Да, это довольно сложно. Нет, дешёвых решений на коленке нет. Книгу дракона читали? Стройте синтаксическое дерево и выполняйте.

Comment: @VladD так а с этого момента поподробней, можете посоветовать литературу/статьи?

Comment: Ну, например, [Dragon Book](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dragon_Book), классика.

Comment: Или Н. Вирт, «[алгоритмы + структуры данных = программы](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algorithms_%2B_Data_Structures_%3D_Programs)» (гуглится). Эта книга вроде проще.

Comment: Пиши компилируемый код на C++.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Окей, ну что же, вам нужен интерпретатор. Давайте-ка разомнёмся и этот самый интерпретатор напишем.

Для начала, нужно составить формальную грамматику вашего языка. Исходя из того, что вы привели в качестве примера программы, можно предположить следующую грамматику:

```
program ::= statement* EOF
compound-statement ::= '{' statement* '}'
statement ::= repeat-statement | function-call | compound-statement
repeat-statement ::= "repeat" "(" number-constant ")" compound-statement
function-call ::= ident "(" arglist ")" 
arglist ::= EMPTY | arg ["," arg]*
arg ::= number-constant | duration-constant
```

Мы видим, что грамматика простая, а значит, её легко распарсить либо вручную, либо через стандартную связку lex/yacc (flex/bison). Парсить через lex/yacc намного проще, и технической работы намного меньше, но давайте напишем парсер вручную, это будет полезнее.

Итак, поскольку наша грамматика [LL(1)](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/LL%281%29) (леворекурсивная, а для определения типа следующего правила достаточно подсмотреть на 1 токен вперёд), напишем простейший парсер [рекурсивного спуска](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9C%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B4_%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%83%D1%80%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE_%D1%81%D0%BF%D1%83%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B0) (recursive descent parser).

Я попробую написать парсер достаточно простой идейно, чтобы его было легко понять, но с другой стороны достаточно общий, чтобы его можно было легко расширить.

Первая часть любого уважающего себя парсера — токенизатор. Мы хотим разделить входную строку на осмысленные *токены*, чтобы не возиться с отдельными символами.

Для начала, какие у нас есть токены? Это

- ключевые слова

  - `repeat`
- пунктуация

  - круглые скобки
  - фигурные скобки
  - запятая
- идентификаторы (имена функций)
- константы

  - числа (наподобие `10`)
  - продолжительность (наподобие `100s`)

Это даёт такой `enum`:

```
enum token_type
{
    // keywords
    tt_repeat,

    tt_ident,
    tt_number,
    tt_duration,

    // punctuation
    tt_lparen,
    tt_rparen,
    tt_lbrace,
    tt_rbrace,
    tt_comma,

    // end of file
    tt_eof,

    // parse error
    tt_error
};
```

и тип данных для токена:

```
struct token
{
    token_type type;
    string string_value;
    long num_value;
};
```

Сам токенизатор будет предоставлять функциональность «подсмотреть» на один токен вперёд, и будет запоминать текущую позицию токена в тексте для удобства отладки:

```
class tokenizer
{
    const string text; // весь текст
    int curridx;       // текущая позиция в тексте
    int endidx;        // длина текста
    int currline, currcol; // текущая строка/номер символа в строке
                           // (нужны лишь для отладки)

    token lookahead;   // следующий токен

    void set_lookahead(); // перейти к следующему токену
                          // и запомнить его в lookahead

public:
    tokenizer(string text) :
        text(text), curridx(0), endidx(text.length()), currline(1), currcol(1)
    {
        lookahead.num_value = 0;
        lookahead.string_value = "";
        set_lookahead();
    }

    token peek_next() { return lookahead; }
    void move_ahead() { set_lookahead(); }
};
```

Основная логика токенизатора находится, понятно, в функции `set_lookahead`. Эту функцию обычно строят на регулярках, наподобие того, как это делает lex. Но мы напишем её вручную.

```
void tokenizer::set_lookahead()
{
    // начнём с пропуска незначащих пробелов
    while (curridx < endidx && isspace(text[curridx]))
    {
        // не забываем следить за нашей позицией в файле
        if (text[curridx] == '\n')
        {
            currcol = 1;
            currline++;
        }
        else
        {
            currcol++;
        }
        // переходим к следующему символу
        curridx++;
    }

    // тут мы точно знаем, где начинается наш следующий токен
    lookahead.lineno = currline;
    lookahead.colno = currcol;
    if (curridx == endidx) // конец файла
    {
        lookahead.type = tt_eof;
        return;
    }

    char c = text[curridx];

    // с пунктуацией всё просто
    if (c == '(' || c == ')' || c == '{' || c == '}' || c == ',')
    {
        lookahead.type = (c == '(') ? tt_lparen :
                         (c == ')') ? tt_rparen :
                         (c == '{') ? tt_lbrace :
                         (c == '}') ? tt_rbrace :
                         tt_comma;
        curridx++;
        currcol++;
        return;
    }

    // если токен начинается с буквы, это ключевое слово или идентификатор
    if (isalpha(c))
    {
        // отделим-ка его сначала в переменную
        string result;
        while (curridx < endidx && isalpha(text[curridx]))
        {
            result += text[curridx];
            curridx++;
            currcol++;
        }

        // проверим ключевые слова
        if (result == "repeat")
        {
            lookahead.type = tt_repeat;
            return;
        }
        // у нас только одно, больше проверять нечего

        // если не ключевое слово, значит, идентификатор
        lookahead.type = tt_ident;
        lookahead.string_value = result;
        return;
    }

    // константы
    if (isdigit(c)) // numeric
    {
        // отделим её от потока текста
        string result;
        // может содержать и буквы в нашей грамматике
        while (curridx < endidx && isalnum(text[curridx]))
        {
            result += text[curridx];
            curridx++;
            currcol++;
        }
        auto c_str = result.c_str();
        char* last_char;
        // есть ли способ попроще узнать, является ли строка числом без "хвоста"?
        long converted = strtol(c_str, &last_char, 10);
        // разобрали все цифры? тогда это число
        if (*last_char == 0)
        {
            lookahead.type = tt_number;
            lookahead.num_value = converted;
            return;
        }
        // в конце s? тогда это продолжительность
        if (*last_char == 's' && *(last_char + 1) == 0)
        {
            lookahead.type = tt_duration;
            lookahead.num_value = converted;
            return;
        }
    }

    // ничего не нашли? окей, запомним, что это ошибка
    lookahead.type = tt_error;
}
```

Продолжаем. Поскольку наш язык простой, мы не будем различать syntax tree и parse tree (то есть, синтаксическое дерево и дерево разбора), и вместо честной реализации visitor'а в syntax tree просто положим виртуальную функцию execute. (Да, я ленюсь.)

Определим классы для syntax tree. Они прямо соответствуют грамматике. (Поскольку это определения, нужно бы везде сослаться на `namespace std`, но я не буду утяжелять код.)

```
struct statement
{
    virtual void execute() = 0;
    virtual ~statement() { }
};

struct function_call : public statement
{
    shared_ptr<installed_function> p_function;
    unique_ptr<arglist> p_args;

    virtual void execute()
    {
        p_function->function(p_args->args);
    }
};

struct compound_statement : public statement
{
    vector<unique_ptr<statement>> statements;
    virtual void execute()
    {
        for (auto& p_statement : statements)
            p_statement->execute();
    }
};

struct repeat_statement : public statement
{
    unique_ptr<statement> p_statement;
    long num_repeat;
    virtual void execute()
    {
        for (long i = 0; i < num_repeat; i++)
            p_statement->execute();
    }
};

struct program : public compound_statement
{
};
```

Отдельно, нам нужны структуры данных для вызовов функций. Пускай аргументы будут типизированными, время `union`'ов прошло.

```
struct arg
{
    virtual ~arg() { }
};

struct number_constant : arg
{
    int value;
};

struct duration_constant : arg
{
    std::chrono::seconds value;
};

struct arglist
{
    vector<unique_ptr<arg>> args;
};
```

Можно, конечно, было бы не усложнять себе жизнь, и просто объявить имена функций ключевыми словами, но это не позволит легко добавлять новые функции.

```
struct installed_function
{
    std::function<void(const std::vector<unique_ptr<arg>>&)> function;
    int argnum;
};
```

Перейдём к собственно парсеру. Он достаточно прямолинеен. Единственная хитрость — функции типа `try_` пытаются найти в текущей точке потока синтаксическую конструкцию, определяя её по первому токену (вспомним, что наша грамматика LL(1)), и возвращают `nullptr`, если первый токен не подходит:

```
class parser
{
    arg* try_parse_arg();
    arglist* try_parse_arglist_until_rparen();
    function_call* try_parse_function_call();
    repeat_statement* try_parse_repeat_statement();
    statement* try_parse_statement();
    compound_statement* try_parse_compound_statement();

public:
    program* parse();

    tokenizer tokenizer;
    installed_functions& functions;

public:
    parser(string input, installed_functions& functions) :
        tokenizer(input), functions(functions)
    {
    }
};
```

Реализация функций прямо соответствует грамматике. Мы сообщаем об ошибках при помощи исключений, поэтому нам придётся пользоваться «умными» указателями, чтобы не было утечек памяти.

```
// program ::= statement* EOF
program* parser::parse()
{
    unique_ptr<program> p(new program());
    while (true)
    {
        // пробуем найти statement
        statement* s = try_parse_statement();
        if (!s) // не нашли? на выход!
            break;
        p->statements.emplace_back(s); // добавляем в список
    }

    // проверяем, что больше в файле ничего нет
    token t = tokenizer.peek_next();
    if (t.type != tt_eof)
        throw parse_exception("extra characters after program end", t);
    return p.release();
}

// compound-statement ::= '{' statement* '}'
compound_statement* parser::try_parse_compound_statement()
{
    // ищем левую фигурную скобку
    token t = tokenizer.peek_next();
    if (t.type != tt_lbrace)
        return nullptr;
    tokenizer.move_ahead();

    unique_ptr<compound_statement> p(new compound_statement());
    // тут в цикле добавляем вложенные statement'ы, как и для program
    while (true)
    {
        statement* s = try_parse_statement();
        if (!s)
            break;
        p->statements.emplace_back(s);
    }

    // здесь должна быть закрывающая фигурная скобка
    t = tokenizer.peek_next();
    if (t.type != tt_rbrace)
        throw parse_exception("expected closing brace after compound statement", t);
    tokenizer.move_ahead();
    return p.release();
}

// statement ::= repeat-statement | function-call | compound-statement
statement* parser::try_parse_statement()
{
    statement* result = nullptr;
    // пропробуем найти repeat statement
    result = try_parse_repeat_statement();
    if (result) // нашли? вот и хорошо
        return result;

    // не нашли? пробуем найти function call
    result = try_parse_function_call();
    if (result) // нашли вызов функции? прекрасно, задание выполнено
        return result;

    // не нашли? может, тут compound statement?
    result = try_parse_compound_statement();
    // нашли-не нашли, не интересно, вернём nullptr в крайнем случае.
    return result;
}

// repeat-statement ::= "repeat" "(" number-constant ")" compound-statement
repeat_statement* parser::try_parse_repeat_statement()
{
    // проверяем, есть ли в начале repeat
    token t = tokenizer.peek_next();
    if (t.type != tt_repeat)
        return nullptr;
    tokenizer.move_ahead();

    // теперь обязательно скобка
    t = tokenizer.peek_next();
    if (t.type != tt_lparen)
        throw parse_exception("opening parenthesis expected", t);
    tokenizer.move_ahead();

    // теперь количество повторений
    t = tokenizer.peek_next();
    if (t.type != tt_number)
        throw parse_exception("number expected", t);
    tokenizer.move_ahead();

    // запомним его в переменую
    long num = t.num_value;

    // тут должна быть закрывающая скобка
    t = tokenizer.peek_next();
    if (t.type != tt_rparen)
        throw parse_exception("closing parenthesis expected", t);
    tokenizer.move_ahead();

    // а за этим всем compound statement
    // ну, это мы умеем
    unique_ptr<compound_statement> s(try_parse_compound_statement());
    if (!s)
        throw parse_exception("compound statement expected after repeat",
                              tokenizer.peek_next());

    // всё нашли? конструируем ответ
    repeat_statement* rs = new repeat_statement();
    rs->num_repeat = num;
    rs->p_statement = move(s);
    return rs;
}

// function-call ::= ident "(" arglist ")"
function_call* parser::try_parse_function_call()
{
    // ищем идентификатор
    token ft = tokenizer.peek_next();
    if (ft.type != tt_ident)
        return nullptr;
    tokenizer.move_ahead();

    // и запомниаем имя функции
    string name = ft.string_value;

    // проверим сначала общий синтаксис, а потом будем выяснять,
    // есть ли такая функция
    token t = tokenizer.peek_next();
    if (t.type != tt_lparen)
        throw parse_exception("left parenthesis expected for function call", t);
    tokenizer.move_ahead();

    unique_ptr<arglist> args(try_parse_arglist_until_rparen());
    if (!args)
        throw parse_exception("argument list not found",
                              tokenizer.peek_next());

    t = tokenizer.peek_next();
    if (t.type != tt_rparen)
        throw parse_exception("right parenthesis expected after function arg list", t);
    tokenizer.move_ahead();

    // обычно проверка семантики (является ли идентификатор функцией) - 
    // задача семантического анализа, то есть, последующих этапов компиляции
    // но поскольку мы пишем игрушечный парсер, мы сделаем это прямо здесь
    auto pfunc = functions.get(name);
    if (!pfunc)
        throw parse_exception("unknown function", ft);
    // проверим заодно и количество аргументов
    if (pfunc->argnum != args->args.size())
        throw parse_exception("argument count for function doesn't match", ft);
    // в принципе, ничего, кроме лени, не мешает нам проверить тут и *типы* аргументов
    // а так придётся проверять типы аргументов во время выполнения
    // и бросать runtime_exception

    function_call* fc = new function_call();
    fc->p_function = pfunc;
    fc->p_args = move(args);
    return fc;
}

// arg ::= number-constant | duration-constant
arg* parser::try_parse_arg()
{
    arg* result = nullptr;
    token t = tokenizer.peek_next();
    if (t.type == tt_number)
    {
        auto r = new number_constant();
        r->value = t.num_value;
        result = r;
    }
    else if (t.type == tt_duration)
    {
        auto r = new duration_constant();
        r->value = chrono::seconds(t.num_value);
        result = r;
    }
    if (result != nullptr)
        tokenizer.move_ahead();
    return result;
}

// arglist ::= EMPTY | arg ["," arg]*
arglist* parser::try_parse_arglist_until_rparen()
{
    unique_ptr<arglist> result(new arglist());
    token t = tokenizer.peek_next();
    if (t.type == tt_rparen)
        return result.release();

    while (true)
    {
        arg* p = try_parse_arg();
        if (!p)
            throw parse_exception("expected argument", tokenizer.peek_next());
        result->args.emplace_back(p);

        t = tokenizer.peek_next();
        if (t.type == tt_rparen)
            return result.release();
        if (t.type != tt_comma)
            throw parse_exception("comma expected between arguments", t);
        tokenizer.move_ahead();
    }
}
```

Отлично, мы прошли бóльшую часть пути. Осталось лишь реализовать механизм добавления функций.

```
class installed_functions
{
    unordered_map<string, shared_ptr<installed_function>> content;

public:
    void install_function(
        function<void(const vector<unique_ptr<arg>>&)> f,
        int argnum,
        string name)
    {
        installed_function* pf = new installed_function;
        pf->function = f;
        pf->argnum = argnum;
        content.insert(make_pair(name, shared_ptr<installed_function>(pf)));
    }

    shared_ptr<installed_function> get(string name)
    {
        auto pfunc = content.find(name);
        if (pfunc == content.end())
            return nullptr;
        return pfunc->second;
    }
};
```

Определим сами функции:

```
void f_pause(const vector<unique_ptr<arg>>& args)
{
    auto parg = dynamic_cast<duration_constant*>(args[0].get());
    if (!parg)
        throw runtime_exception("argument type mismatch in function pause");
    auto duration = parg->value;
    cout << "pause: " << duration.count() << " seconds" << endl;
}

void f_click(const vector<unique_ptr<arg>>& args)
{
    auto parg1 = dynamic_cast<number_constant*>(args[0].get());
    auto parg2 = dynamic_cast<number_constant*>(args[1].get());
    if (!parg1 || !parg2)
        throw runtime_exception("argument type mismatch in function click");
    auto x = parg1->value;
    auto y = parg2->value;
    cout << "click: (" << x << ", " << y << ")" << endl;
}
```

И можно тестировать:

```
string text = "repeat (8)\n"
              "{\n"
              "click(10,10)\n"
              "pause(100s)\n"
              "click(10,10)\n"
              "repeat(2)\n"
              "   {\n"
              "   pause(10)\n"
              "   }\n"
              "}";

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    installed_functions functions;
    functions.install_function(f_pause, 1, "pause");
    functions.install_function(f_click, 2, "click");

    parser p(text, functions);
    unique_ptr<program> tree;
    try
    {
        tree.reset(p.parse());
        cout << "executing:" << endl;
        tree->execute();
    }
    catch (const parse_exception& ex)
    {
        cerr << "parse exception at line " << ex.row
             << ", char " << ex.col << ": " << ex.text << endl;
    }
    catch (const runtime_exception& ex)
    {
        cerr << "runtime exception: " << ex.text << endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Получаем вывод:

> executing:
>   click: (10, 10)
>   pause: 100 seconds
>   click: (10, 10)
>   runtime exception: argument type mismatch in function pause

Ах, да, мы же неправильно указали тип аргумента для `pause`! Меняем `pause(10)` на `pause(10s)`, всё работает как часы.

---

**Обновление**: Чуть более продвинутая версия того же парсера [доступна на гитхабе](https://github.com/vladd/SimpleParser2).

Comment: Все конечно хорошо, но почему для индексации строк использован int вместо size_t?

Comment: @gbg: Ну да, там есть пара недостатков по коду :-D Я ещё кроме всего прочего не использую современные конструкции, т. к. мой компилятор (VS 2012) до них не дорос. И возможно злоупотребляю динамическим выделением памяти.

Comment: @gbg: А ещё я изобретаю велосипед и не использую lex/yacc. Кстати, надо бы переписать на yacc, и правда.

Comment: насчет повсеместного auto, например, у меня двойственное мнение. С одной стороны, написание кода ускоряется. С другой, код становится менее прозрачен гражданам, которые изучают код без IDE. И с третьей, такой код чуть сложнее рефакторить. Так что все это вкусовщина :-)

Comment: @gbg: Мой основной язык C# (и это, судя по всему, заметно).

Comment: @gdb, "почему для индексации строк использован int вместо size_t" тоже предпочитаю int, т.к. с size_t можно легко нарваться на проблемы в случае, если происходит отрицательное переполнение.

Comment: Это... круто. Вот на таких примерах учиться - самое то, спасибо!

Answer (score 4):

Если это не к какому-то готовому интерпретатору - тогда примерно так :
1. разбиваем на отдельные токены :
['repeat', '(', '8', ')', '{', 'click', '(', '10', '10', ')', 'pause', '(', '100s', ')', 'click', '(', '10', '10', ')', 'repeat', '(', '2', ')', '{', 'pause', '(', '10', ')', '}', '}'
2. строим по ним дерево (как вариант - подобное :

- repeat
- - 8
- - block
- - - click
- - - - 10
- - - - 10
- - - pause
- - - - 100s
- - - click
- - - - 10
- - - - 10
- - - repeat
- - - - 2
- - - - block
- - - - - pause
- - - - - - 10

И начинаем выполнять с верхнего узла.
Хотя по хорошему - все несколько сложнее

Answer (score 1):

YACC вам в помощь. Такая простая грамматика пишется очень быстро даже с нулевыми знаниями.

Comment: ... и lex тогда уже. Или лучше flex/bison.

Comment: Да для такого простого кода проще, пожалуй, без lex...

Comment: Мне сложно согласиться, что без токенизатора проще. Хотя бы незначащие пробелы надо выкусывать как-то. Или вы имеете в виду ручную токенизацию?

Comment: Постарайтесь писать более развернутые ответы. Поясните, на чем основано ваше утверждение?