# Реализация синтаксического анализатора

Tags: алгоритм, компиляция, парсер

Пишу интерпретатор для "микро" языка программирования, заточенного под небольшие специфические задачи (ну и забавы ради). Лексический анализатор я написал, работает корректно, возвращает список лексем. Осталось синтаксический анализатор написать. И вот тут пара вопросов есть.

Как, собственно, реализовать саму грамматику? Первое, что приходит в голову - куча `if - else`'ов, сравнение последовательностей лексем и вызов соответствующих методов (то есть, для каждого оператора - свой метод, который парсит корректность этого выражения). Но, по-моему, это не самый рациональный вариант(?). Есть более профессиональные способы? Перечитал много статей, в том числе и на stackoverflow, но ничего не нашел/не понял. Куда копать? А еще лучше примеры кода.

P.S. вопрос именно в построении самого процесса интерпретации (то есть, например, как парсить мат. выражения я представляю).

Comment: Ну вот вам пример интерпретатора на C++: http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/452045/10105

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Вы про BNF читали ? Я когда свой интерпретатор делал, составил для  себя небольшой шаблонный язык для описания языка, потом мой знакомый полез в интернет и набрел на BNF, который очень похож на то, что я сделал. Правда в итоге я признал BNF слишком сложным, вернее он то элементарен, но описывать через него слишком громоздко. Пришел к несколько другим конструкциям. В итоге никаких if проверяющих на конкретные операторы у меня нет. Есть просто таблица, описывающая шаблоны, сам интерпретатор обрабатывает только кодовые слова самого шаблона (я делал для наглядности слова, но по факту роль конечно играют ID). Вот пара простеньких примеров:

```
Оператор 'кавычки': <SELF> <TEXT> <SELF> (На самом деле собирается на уровне лексера,
      но представлен как оператор, что бы с ним могли взаимодействовать соседние операторы)
Большинство бинарных операторов (у которых 2 аргумента) <VALUE> <SELF> <VALUE>
```

Обработчик шаблонов понимает, что VALUE - это *Значение*, а следовательно на его месте может быть нечто (набор других операторов), возвращающих *Значение* и уходит для их захвата из потока лексем в рекурсию.
Правда потом шаблоны пришлось сильно усложнять, Добавляя *маркеры* для всяких экзотических ситуаций, в основном связанных с допустимостью конкретных операторов в конкретных *контекстах*. Например, оператор (ключевое слово) private, допустимо только в *контексте* объявления класса. Или лексема '=' в зависимости от *контекста* может интерпретироваться как "*оператор присвоения*" или как *модификатор* оператора "*объявление переменной*". Вот так, например, выглядит у меня "оператор if": `<SELF> <(> <VALUE NPOS> <)> <OPERS NULL> <OPERS OPTGRP; CLASS #if; SET if-main;>`.

Это я к тому, что когда делать начинаешь, кажется, что все не очень сложно описывается, а потом реальный мир заставляет все наворачивать и наворачивать усложнений.

Да, и помните про приоритеты операторов и то что бывают лево и правосторонние (порядок выполнения слева-направо или справа-налево, при одинаковых приоритетах).

На выходе интерпретатора по хорошему должно получится дерево выполнения, что то типа такого: для `a = b + c - d`,

```
oper= {
       oper+ {
               <b>, 
               oper- { <c>, <d> }
             }
      }
```

Понятно, что это дерево внутри программы просто в виде данных, с id операторов и их аргументами. В таком формате привожу просто для наглядности, что от чего зависит. Причем выполнение по этому дереву достаточно просто, обработчик (или сборщик инструкций процессора) спускается по ветви дерева до самого низа и возвращаясь начинает выполнять все по дороге, т.е. в этом примере сначала выполняется `-` над операндами `c` и `d`, потом результат, как операнд, поступает оператору `+` и уже его результат поступает оператору 'присвоить'. Ошибки тут нет, в большинстве языков, равно-приоритетные операторы + и - выполняются справа-налево, т.е. они правосторонние.

На а обработчик - тупо массив id-оператора -> исполняющая функция. опять же, никаких if, полезли в массив по индексу id-оператора, взяли указатель на функцию, вызвали ее.

Да, узнайте кто такие Як с Бизоном ([Yacc](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yacc), [Bison](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNU_bison)), в принципе полезные животные, я этим путем не пошел, но просто потому, что люблю делать велосипеды :)

Answer (score 3):

> то есть, например, как парсить мат. выражения я представляю

При желании такой же алгоритм можно использовать и для программы.

Конструкции if-else, for можно рассматривать как операторы, begin/end как парные скобки и так далее. Соответственно, внутри функция, реализующая оператор, получает дерево и обрабатывает его. Т. е. она именно запускает вычисление своих аргументов по необходимости и необходимое число раз.

PS: Я так простенький интерпретатор паскалеподобного синтаксиса делал.

Answer (score 3):

Если "операторов" не много, то почему и не сделать серию if-else. Если же операторов "много", то тут оптимально сделать обычный map (он же словарь, он же dict, hash и так далее), в котором ключами будут имена "операторов", а значениями - ссылки на функции/методы. В этом случае добавление нового метода - это одна строка в мап и собственно отпределение функции для обработки.

В больших системах делают хитрее - используют кодогенератор. Например, функции, которые обрабатывают операторы, называют по особому. А система сборки (make файл) перед сборкой запускает скрипт/программу, которая сканирует файлы, находит эти все функции и генерирует либо большой switch, или серию if-else.

Я упомянул switch - на нем также можно сделать красиво и просто. И даже тремя способами. Первый способ заключается в том, что switch оперирует по первому символу имени оператора, а внутри каждого case есть серия if. Второй способ - по имени оператора вычисляется crc, и дальше уже обычный case. Но и тут иногда нужно добавлять if - вполне может быть, что у некоторых имен crc совпадет. Последний способ - это дерево. На первом уровне - первый символ, от них отходит второй уровень, куда включаются вторые символы.  В большинстве случаев уже на третьем уровне будет понятно имя.

Очень рекомендуется читать [книгу с драконом](http://www.ozon.ru/context/detail/id/3829076/) (я прямо сейчас читаю второе издание - там все эти вопросы разбираются).