# Парсинг строки в условное выражение

Tags: c++, синтаксический-анализ

Допустим, есть строка: `5>6 | 2<3 & 1<5`. Как мне перевести эту строку в нормальное условие? Это строка может быть бесконечной. Я примерно понимаю, как перевести строку, если сравнивать подряд до знака `|` или `&`, но как сделать так, чтобы сначала он смотрел на выражение со знаком `&`? Строка вводится с клавиатуры. Нужно реализовать мини компилятор условного выражения.

Comment: Мини компилятор, говорите? В общем, тут надо при разборе учитывать приоритеты операций. Для примера можете посмотреть [код простого калькулятора](http://pastebin.com/stQw5kyc) арифметических выражений, передаваемых в строках. (а [это](http://pastebin.com/nnQN8zcX) примерно то же самое, но с переменными и функциями (в т.ч. предоставляемыми пользователем))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Что понимать под "нормальное условие" - непонятно, при том, что ваша строка однозначно дает `true` или `false`. Так что я опишу, как *вычислить* это значение.

Скобок нет?
Простейший вариант словами поясню примерно так... Как разобрать подвыражение, вы пишете, что вам понятно (я имею в виду, само `a>b` или там `c<d`).

Тогда - разобрали первое, внесли в **стек** его **значение** (`true` или `false`), следующий за ним знак туда же, разобрали следующее, посмотрели на спрятанный знак - если `&`, сразу достаем из стека знак и предыдущее значение, вычисляем и результат заносим в стек. Если же там знак `|`, просто добавляем в стек новое значение и идем за следующим знаком. После того, как разберете все, в стеке останутся только данные для `|`. Снимаем и вычисляем.

Это все можно слегка оптимизировать - если в какой-то момент получили `true`, а за ним знак `|` - дальше можно не считать :) Как и `false` с последующим `&` - сразу можно пропускать все до следующего знака...

Если со скобками - принцип тот же, но чуть морочливее. Просто надо вносить скобку, и при достижении закрывающей можно вычислять все подвыражение в скобках.

А вообще задание у вас не последнее, думаю, стоит вам почитать что-то по синтаксическому анализу, те же "Компиляторы" Ахо-Ульмана-Сети-Лам.

Answer (score 7):

Давайте-ка напишем полновесный парсер, с грамматикой, токенизатором, и возможностью лёгкого расширения. За основу я взял вот этот парсер: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/452045/10105

Итак, для начала токенизация. Определяем тип токена:

```
enum token_type
{
    tt_number,

    // comparison
    tt_gt, tt_lt, tt_eq, tt_ge, tt_le,

    // logicals
    tt_and, tt_or,

    // punctuation
    tt_lparen, tt_rparen,

    // end of file
    tt_eof,

    // parse error
    tt_error
};

struct token
{
    token_type type;
    long num_value;
    size_t colno, lineno;
};
```

Сам токенизатор можно брать практически без изменений:

```
class tokenizer
{
    const string text; // весь текст
    int curridx;       // текущая позиция в тексте
    int endidx;        // длина текста
    int currline, currcol; // текущая строка/номер символа в строке
                           // (нужны лишь для отладки)

    token lookahead;   // следующий токен

    void set_lookahead(); // перейти к следующему токену
                          // и запомнить его в lookahead

public:
    tokenizer(string text) :
        text(text), curridx(0), endidx(text.length()), currline(1), currcol(1)
    {
        lookahead.num_value = 0;
        set_lookahead();
    }

    token peek_next() { return lookahead; }
    void move_ahead() { set_lookahead(); }
};

void tokenizer::set_lookahead()
{
    // начнём с пропуска незначащих пробелов
    while (curridx < endidx && isspace(text[curridx]))
    {
        // не забываем следить за нашей позицией в файле
        if (text[curridx] == '\n')
        {
            currcol = 1;
            currline++;
        }
        else
        {
            currcol++;
        }
        // переходим к следующему символу
        curridx++;
    }

    // тут мы точно знаем, где начинается наш следующий токен
    lookahead.lineno = currline;
    lookahead.colno = currcol;
    if (curridx == endidx) // конец файла
    {
        lookahead.type = tt_eof;
        return;
    }

    char c = text[curridx];

    // с пунктуацией и логическими операциями всё просто
    if (c == '(' || c == ')' || c == '&' || c == '|' || c == '=')
    {
        lookahead.type = (c == '(') ? tt_lparen :
                         (c == ')') ? tt_rparen :
                         (c == '&') ? tt_and :
                         (c == '|') ? tt_or :
                         tt_eq;
        curridx++;
        currcol++;
        return;
    }

    // со сравнениями не намного сложнее
    if (c == '>' || c == '<')
    {
        curridx++;
        currcol++;
        if (curridx < endidx && text[curridx] == '=')
        {
            curridx++;
            currcol++;
            lookahead.type = (c == '>') ? tt_ge : tt_le;
        }
        else
        {
            lookahead.type = (c == '>') ? tt_gt : tt_lt;
        }
        return;
    }

    // константы
    if (isdigit(c)) // numeric
    {
        // отделим её от потока текста
        string result;
        while (curridx < endidx && isdigit(text[curridx]))
        {
            result += text[curridx];
            curridx++;
            currcol++;
        }
        long value = stol(result);
        lookahead.type = tt_number;
        lookahead.num_value = value;
        return;
    }

    // ничего не нашли? окей, запомним, что это ошибка
    lookahead.type = tt_error;
}
```

Теперь нам понадобятся несущие структуры данных. Они очень простые:

```
template<typename TResult>
struct expression
{
    virtual TResult compute() = 0;
    virtual ~expression() { }
};

struct constant_expression : public expression<long>
{
    long value;
    virtual long compute() { return value; }
};

struct comparison_expression : public expression<bool>
{
    token_type comparison_type;
    unique_ptr<expression<long>> lhs, rhs;
    virtual bool compute()
    {
        long left = lhs->compute(), right = rhs->compute();
        switch (comparison_type)
        {
        case tt_eq:
            return left == right;
        case tt_gt:
            return left >  right;
        case tt_ge:
            return left >= right;
        case tt_lt:
            return left <  right;
        case tt_le:
            return left <= right;
        default:
            throw exception("impossible");
        }
    }
};

struct logical_expression : public expression<bool>
{
    token_type comparison_type;
    vector<unique_ptr<expression<bool>>> operands;
    virtual bool compute()
    {
        vector<bool> results;
        transform(begin(operands), end(operands), inserter(results, begin(results)),
                  [](auto& op) { return op->compute(); });
        switch (comparison_type)
        {
        case tt_and:
            return all_of(begin(results), end(results), [](auto v) { return v; });
        case tt_or:
            return any_of(begin(results), end(results), [](auto v) { return v; });
        default:
            throw exception("impossible");
        }
    }
};
```

Теперь запишем нашу грамматику. Она у нас тоже несложная, то её можно легко расширить:

```
logical_expression ::=
    logical_factor [ '|' logical_factor ]*

logical_factor ::=
    logical_term [ '&' logical_term ]*

logical_term ::=
    '(' logical_expression ')' | comparison

comparison ::=
    numeric_expression COMP numeric_expression

numeric_expression ::= numeric_constant

COMP ::= '>' | '<' | '>=' | '<=' | '='
```

Согласно этой грамматике, строим парсер рекурсивного спуска:

```
class parser
{
    expression<bool>* try_parse_logical_expression();
    expression<bool>* try_parse_logical_factor();
    expression<bool>* try_parse_logical_term();
    comparison_expression* try_parse_comparison();
    expression<long>* try_parse_numeric_expression();

    tokenizer tokenizer;

public:
    expression<bool>* parse();

public:
    parser(string input) :
        tokenizer(input)
    {
    }
};
```

Имплементация, один метод на правило:

```
expression<bool>* parser::parse()
{
    unique_ptr<expression<bool>> p(try_parse_logical_expression());
    token t = tokenizer.peek_next();
    if (!p)
        throw parse_exception("expected logical expression", t);

    // проверяем, что больше в файле ничего нет
    if (t.type != tt_eof)
        throw parse_exception("extra characters after program end", t);
    return p.release();
}

//logical_expression ::= logical_factor [ '&' logical_factor ]*
expression<bool>* parser::try_parse_logical_expression()
{
    unique_ptr<expression<bool>> operand(try_parse_logical_factor());
    if (!operand)
        return nullptr;

    token t = tokenizer.peek_next();
    if (t.type != tt_or)
        return operand.release();

    unique_ptr<logical_expression> p(new logical_expression());
    p->operands.emplace_back(operand.release());
    p->comparison_type = tt_or;

    while (t.type == tt_or)
    {
        tokenizer.move_ahead();
        unique_ptr<expression<bool>> operand(try_parse_logical_factor());
        if (!operand)
            throw parse_exception("expected logical expression", t);
        p->operands.emplace_back(operand.release());
        t = tokenizer.peek_next();
    }
    return p.release();
}

//logical_factor ::= logical_term [ '&' logical_term ]*
expression<bool>* parser::try_parse_logical_factor()
{
    unique_ptr<expression<bool>> operand(try_parse_logical_term());
    if (!operand)
        return nullptr;

    token t = tokenizer.peek_next();
    if (t.type != tt_and)
        return operand.release();

    unique_ptr<logical_expression> p(new logical_expression());
    p->operands.emplace_back(operand.release());
    p->comparison_type = tt_and;

    while (t.type == tt_and)
    {
        tokenizer.move_ahead();
        unique_ptr<expression<bool>> operand(try_parse_logical_term());
        if (!operand)
            throw parse_exception("expected logical expression", t);
        p->operands.emplace_back(operand.release());
        t = tokenizer.peek_next();
    }
    return p.release();
}

//logical_term ::= '(' logical_expression ')' | comparison
expression<bool>* parser::try_parse_logical_term()
{
    token t = tokenizer.peek_next();
    if (t.type == tt_lparen)
    {
        tokenizer.move_ahead();
        unique_ptr<expression<bool>> p(try_parse_logical_expression());
        t = tokenizer.peek_next();
        if (p == nullptr)
            throw parse_exception("expected logical expression in parentheses", t);
        if (t.type == tt_rparen)
            throw parse_exception("expected closing parenthesis", t);
        tokenizer.move_ahead();
        return p.release();
    }

    // else it must be a comparison or nothing
    return try_parse_comparison();
}

// comparison ::= numeric_expression COMP numeric_expression
comparison_expression* parser::try_parse_comparison()
{
    unique_ptr<expression<long>> lhs(try_parse_numeric_expression());
    if (lhs == nullptr)
        return nullptr;

    token t = tokenizer.peek_next();
    if (t.type != tt_gt && t.type != tt_ge &&
        t.type != tt_lt && t.type != tt_le && t.type != tt_eq)
        throw parse_exception("numeric comparison expected", t);
    tokenizer.move_ahead();

    unique_ptr<expression<long>> rhs(try_parse_numeric_expression());
    if (rhs == nullptr)
        throw parse_exception("numeric expression expected", t);

    unique_ptr<comparison_expression> p(new comparison_expression());
    p->lhs.swap(lhs);
    p->rhs.swap(rhs);
    p->comparison_type = t.type;
    return p.release();
}

//numeric_expression :: = numeric_constant
expression<long>* parser::try_parse_numeric_expression()
{
    token t = tokenizer.peek_next();
    if (t.type != tt_number)
        return nullptr;
    tokenizer.move_ahead();

    unique_ptr<constant_expression> p(new constant_expression());
    p->value = t.num_value;
    return p.release();
}
```

Нам ещё нужен микрокласс с исключением:

```
struct parse_exception : exception
{
    int row;
    int col;
    string text;

    parse_exception(string text, token t) : text(text), row(t.lineno), col(t.colno)
    {
    }
};
```

И можно тестировать:

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    string text = "5>6 | 2<3 & 1<5";
    parser p(text);
    unique_ptr<expression<bool>> expr;
    try
    {
        expr.reset(p.parse());
        cout << "executing:" << endl;
        bool result = expr->compute();
        cout << "result: " << boolalpha << result << endl;
    }
    catch (const parse_exception& ex)
    {
        cerr << "parse exception at line " << ex.row
            << ", char " << ex.col << ": " << ex.text << endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Всё!

---

Дополнение: добавим поддержку идентификаторов.

Добавим новый тип токена:

```
enum token_type
{
    tt_number,

    tt_ident, // <---
```

Расширим токенизатор, чтобы он понимал идентификаторы. Для этого добавим в конец функции `set_lookahead`:

```
    // если токен начинается с буквы, это ключевое слово или идентификатор
    if (isalpha(c))
    {
        // отделим-ка его сначала в переменную
        string result;
        while (curridx < endidx && isalpha(text[curridx]))
        {
            result += text[curridx];
            curridx++;
            currcol++;
        }

        // если не ключевое слово, значит, идентификатор
        lookahead.type = tt_ident;
        lookahead.name = result;
        return;
    }

    // ничего не нашли? окей, запомним, что это ошибка
    lookahead.type = tt_error;
}
```

Нам нужна ещё структура, представляющая собой ссылку на переменную. Поскольку переменная может быть не определена, нам придётся ввести ошибки времени выполнения.

```
struct variable_expression : public expression<long>
{
    string name;
    virtual long compute()
    {
        auto iter = variables.find(name);
        if (iter == variables.end())
            throw runtime_exception("unknown variable: " + name);
        return iter->second;
    }
};
```

Ну и новый тип исключения:

```
struct runtime_exception : exception
{
    string text;

    runtime_exception(string text) : text(text)
    {
    }
};
```

Расширяем грамматику:

```
numeric_expression ::= numeric_constant | variable
```

и имплементацию:

```
//numeric_expression :: = numeric_constant | variable
expression<long>* parser::try_parse_numeric_expression()
{
    token t = tokenizer.peek_next();
    if (t.type == tt_number)
    {
        tokenizer.move_ahead();

        unique_ptr<constant_expression> p(new constant_expression());
        p->value = t.num_value;
        return p.release();
    }

    if (t.type == tt_ident)
    {
        tokenizer.move_ahead();

        unique_ptr<variable_expression> p(new variable_expression());
        p->name = t.name;
        return p.release();
    }
    return nullptr;
}
```

Ну и тест:

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    variables["two"] = 2;
    variables["five"] = 5;

    string text = "five>6 | two<3 & 1>7";
    parser p(text);
    unique_ptr<expression<bool>> expr;
    try
    {
        expr.reset(p.parse());
        cout << "executing:" << endl;
        bool result = expr->compute();
        cout << "result: " << boolalpha << result << endl;
    }
    catch (const parse_exception& ex)
    {
        cerr << "parse exception at line " << ex.row
             << ", char " << ex.col << ": " << ex.text << endl;
    }
    catch (const runtime_exception& ex)
    {
        cerr << "runtime exception: " << ex.text << endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

---

Обновление: упростил разбор числовых констант в токенизаторе (он был позаимствован из другого ответа, где усложнение имело смысл).

Comment: Объясните пожалуйста, а как быть с идентификаторами которые были объявлены ранее например a > 5

Comment: @Артем: Ну, для них нужен отдельный синтаксический элемент. И контейнер значений. Сейчас добавлю в грамматику :)

Comment: @Артем: Дописал.

Comment: @Qwertiy: У меня в ответе слово «простейший» не встречается :)

Answer (score 0):

Вот написал бесскобочный вариант, с операциями AND, OR, XOR и сравнения >, <, >=, <=, ==

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <cctype>
bool calc_pair(const char*& s, bool& err);
bool calc_logic(const char* s, bool& err);

int main(void){
   bool err, res;
   bool test  =  5>6 | 2<3 &  1 <= 2 & 4 >= 9 ^ 4 >= 2 & 7==7;
   char s[64] = "5>6 | 2<3 &  1 <= 2 & 4 >= 9 ^ 4 >= 2 & 7==7";
  /*
   std::cout << "Enter expr: ";
   std::cin.getline(s, sizeof(s));
   std::cin.sync();
  */
   res = calc_logic(s, err);
   if(err){
      std::cout << " res: " << res  << std::endl;
      std::cout << "test: " << test << std::endl;
   } else
      std::cout << "error calc!" << std::endl;
   return 0;
}

bool calc_logic(const char* s, bool& err){
   char c, c1;
   bool a, b, v;

   err = true;
   a   = calc_pair(s, err);
   if(! err)
      return false;

   while(*s){
      c = *s++;
      b = calc_pair(s, err);
      if(! err)
         break;

      switch(c) {
         case '&':
            a &= b;
            break;
         case '|':
         case '^':
            if(*s == '&'){
               v = b;
               while(*s){
                  c1 = *s;
                  if(c1 == '|' || c1 == '^')
                      break;
                  ++s;

                  b = calc_pair(s, err);
                  if(! err)
                      return false;

                  if(c1 == '&')
                      v &= b;
                }
                b = v;
             }

             if(c == '|')
               a |= b;
             else if(c == '^')
               a ^= b;
           break;
        default:
           err = false;
           return false;
    }
  }
  return a;
}

bool calc_pair(const char*& s, bool& err){
   long  a, b;
   char* p;
   bool  res;

   err = false;
   a   = strtol(s, &p, 10);
   if(s == p)
      return false;
   s = p;

   while(*s && isspace(*s))
      ++s;

   int n = 1, i = -1;
   if(*s == '<'){
       if(*(s + 1) == '='){
           i = 3;
           n = 2;
       } else
           i = 0;
   } else if(*s == '>'){
       if(*(s + 1) == '='){
           i = 4;
           n = 2;
       } else
           i = 1;
   } else if(*s == '=' && *(s + 1) == '='){
        i = 2;
        n = 2;
   }

   if(i == -1)
       return false;

   s += n;
   b  = strtol(s, &p, 10);
   if(s == p)
       return false;
   s = p;

   switch(i){
   case 0:
      res = a < b;
      break;
   case 1:
      res = a > b;
      break;
   case 2:
      res = a == b;
      break;
   case 3:
      res = a <= b;
      break;
   case 4:
      res = a >= b;
      break;
   }

   err = true;
   while(*s && isspace(*s))
       ++s;
   return res;
}
```