# Регулярное выражение для лексического анализатора C#

Tags: c#, регулярные-выражения, синтаксический-анализ, лексер

Стоит задача реализовать лексер для конструкции if/else на C#, решил реализовать это путем последовательного пропуска входной строки через регэкспы, с которыми начал разбираться недавно. При написании регэкспов для констант/переменных использую группы без захвата перед и после группы захвата для адекватного распознавания лексем, однако проблема в том, что если матчи групп без захвата совпадают, то значение справа не распознается. Если убрать группу без захвата перед основной группой, все значения распознаются. Например, без первой проверочной группы: [image: Пример 1]

С проверочной группой: [image: Пример 2]

Подобное наблюдается только на стыке матчей: [image: Пример 3]

То есть, как видно из примера, в блоке else промежуточное значение n не выделяется, ибо находится "на стыке".

Само выражение (со всеми группами):

```
/(?:[-+*\/=<>{)(;]{1})([A-Za-z]{1}[A-Za-z0-9]*)(?:[-;+*\/=<>)]{1})/
```

Строка:

```
if(dsf==35){x=y/10;}else{y=n/25+n;}
```

Что следует изменить, дабы проходила проверка и при этом распознавались все искомые лексемы (в данном случае переменные)?

UPD: задача с анализом решена, осталась реализация синтаксического анализа [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Код паттернов, если кому интересно (cлева - токен, справа - его индексы во входной строке):

```
public static Dictionary<string, string> Patterns = new Dictionary<string, string>()
        {
            {"variable", @"(?:[-+*\/=<>{)(;]{1})([A-Za-z]{1}[A-Za-z0-9]*)"},
            {"operator", @"(?:[A-Za-z0-9]+?)([<>]{1}[=]?|[=]{2}|!{1}={1}|[-+*\/=]+?)"},
            {"punctuation", @"([)({};]+?)"},
            {"keyword", @"(if|else)(?:[({]+?)"},
            {"constante", @"(?:[-+*\/=<>(]+?)([-]?[\d]+[.]?[\d]*)"}
        };
```

[Cсылка на regex101](http://regex101.com/r/wA7lG7/1) с отредактированным выражением, возможно у вас будут еще замечания:

Comment: Стоит привести не только выражение, но и текст, который вы пытаетесь им обработать - чтобы другим не пришлось набирать с картинки :)

Comment: у вас во всех случаях после любых арифметических действий или равно  не выделяется.

уберите последнюю группу и все заработает

Comment: @splash58 да, действительно, последняя группа оказалась лишней, спасибо) 2 часа бился, искал причину в первой и второй группе, а оказывается в последней.

Comment: Я бы не советовал использовать регулярки для чего-либо сложнее чем простое разбиение на токены (что собственно и должно являться задачей лексера). Представьте себе, как вы будете разбирать вложенные `if`'ы, для начала.

Comment: А так — просто ищите в исходном тесте `if` и `else`. Возможно, вам придётся ещё отлавливать строковые константы и комментарии, чтобы не находить `if` в них.

Comment: Круто конечно, но может вместо скринов дадите ссылки на regex101 ?

Comment: Это ваш сокурсник, да? http://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/519231/10105

Comment: @VladD, я и разбиваю на токены. Следующей задачей сейчас стоит синтаксический анализ, но это уже совсем другая история.

Comment: @Сергей, перенесите всю важную информацию из комментариев непосредственно в вопрос

Comment: @VladD . вариант с вложенными if не рассматривался по причине отсутствия данной фичи в ТЗ, однако если несколько править паттерн для if/else, приведенный мной выше, этот момент также решается.

Comment: @Сергей: Если вы разбиваете на токены, тогда не вполне понятно, причём тут конструкция if/else. Токенизатор должен нормально принимать текст `else if if x > < > if = else`, и выдавать наружу токены `ELSE IF IF IDENT(x) GT LT GT IF EQ ELSE`. То есть он должен не «распознавать конструкцию if/else», а просто распознавать токены `IF` и `ELSE`.

Comment: @VladD возможно моя реализация не полностью соответствует понятию лексера, однако я исходил из принципа утиной типизации, то бишь проверки самого токена и его окружения, т.к. в реальной конструкции может быть ключевое слово if и обязательно следующая за ним "(", а перед ним должен быть также некоторый нетерминал (но т.к. в моем случае я рассматриваю сразу входную конструкцию, начинающуюся с if ( что, возможно, и не правильно)) этот момент я опустил. Просто само слово "if" может встретиться в разном контексте, например как часть имени переменной somevarIF.

Comment: @VladD то, что делает моя программа (на скринах выше), совершенно неправильно?

Comment: Я не смотрел, но как-то у вас всё слишком сложно.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Вы подходите слишком сложно. Напишите просто регулярки, которые распознают кусок текста с начала строки. После этого для того, чтобы найти следующий токен, примените все регулярки и найдите самое длинное совпадение. (Вам нужно лишь позаботиться, чтобы ключевые слова идентификаторы имели преимущество перед идентификаторами.) Получив токен, откусывайте от строки отматченный кусок, и повторяйте сначала. Никакие capture groups вовсе не нужны.

Вот вам скелет:

```
class Program
{
    enum TokenType
    {
        Comparison,
        Punct,
        If,
        Else,
        Ident, // должно идти после ключевых слов!
        NumLiteral
    };

    class Token
    {
        public TokenType Type;
        public string StringValue;
        public double NumericValue;
        // сюда стоит ещё добавить информацию о позиции в исходном тексте
    }

    // регулярки, описывающие лексему, начинаются с ^, чтобы матчить только в начале
    Dictionary<TokenType, Regex> regexes = new Dictionary<TokenType, Regex>()
    {
        [TokenType.Comparison] = new Regex(@"^(>=?|<=?|==)", RegexOptions.Compiled),
        [TokenType.Punct] = new Regex(@"^[,)(}{;]", RegexOptions.Compiled),
        [TokenType.If] = new Regex(@"^if", RegexOptions.Compiled),
        [TokenType.Else] = new Regex(@"^else", RegexOptions.Compiled),
        [TokenType.Ident] = new Regex(@"^[a-zA-Z_][a-zA-Z_0-9]*", RegexOptions.Compiled),
        [TokenType.NumLiteral] = new Regex(@"^[0-9]+(\.[0-9]+)?", RegexOptions.Compiled)
    };

    // что ещё записать в токен?
    Dictionary<TokenType, Action<string, Token>> creators =
        new Dictionary<TokenType, Action<string, Token>>()
        {
            [TokenType.Comparison] = (s, token) => token.StringValue = s,
            [TokenType.Punct] = (s, token) => token.StringValue = s,
            [TokenType.If] = (s, token) => { },
            [TokenType.Else] = (s, token) => { },
            [TokenType.Ident] = (s, token) => token.StringValue = s,
            [TokenType.NumLiteral] = (s, token) => token.NumericValue = double.Parse(s)
        };

    // а вот и вся логика:
    IEnumerable<Token> Tokenize(string text)
    {
        // откусываем пробелы
        var remainingText = text.TrimStart();
        while (remainingText != "")
        {
            // находим наиболее подходящий паттерн:
            var bestMatch =
               (from pair in regexes
                let tokenType = pair.Key
                let regex = pair.Value
                let match = regex.Match(remainingText)
                let matchLen = match.Length
                // упорядочиваем по длине, а если длина одинаковая - по типу токена
                orderby matchLen descending, tokenType
                select new { tokenType, text = match.Value, matchLen }).First();

            // если везде только 0, ошибка
            if (bestMatch.matchLen == 0)
                throw new Exception("Unknown lexeme");

            var token = new Token() { Type = bestMatch.tokenType };
            creators[bestMatch.tokenType](bestMatch.text, token);
            yield return token;

            // откусываем распознанный кусок и пробелы после него
            remainingText = remainingText.Substring(bestMatch.matchLen).TrimStart();
        }
    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        new Program().Run();
    }

    void Run()
    {
        var text = "else if if x > < > if == else; 25.0 7";
        foreach (var token in Tokenize(text))
            Console.WriteLine(token.Type);
    }
}
```

Выдаёт:

> Else
>   If
>   If
>   Ident
>   Comparison
>   Comparison
>   Comparison
>   If
>   Comparison
>   Else
>   Punct
>   NumLiteral
>   NumLiteral

Comment: _[TokenType.Comparison] = new Regex(@"^(>=?|<=?|==)", RegexOptions.Compiled),_ - какой-то новый тип инициализации? вроде в пятом так еще нельзя было?

Comment: @Grundy: Угу, новый. Всё равно что `{ TokenType.Comparison, new Regex(...) }`, но понтовее :)

Comment: Что-то мне кажется предыдущий вариант был понятнее :)

Comment: Ну, это в пару к `regexes[TokenType.Comparison] = new Regex(...)`. Привыкнуть легко.

Comment: @VladD,здравствуйте, решил не создавать новый вопрос дабы не засорять ленту, а обратиться за помощью к вам.Сейчас пишу синтаксический анализатор исходя собственно из лексического, и вот не могу определиться, какую структуру использовать для таблицы анализа. Я создал Dictionary<int, Delegate> Rules, вот теперь мне нужна структура, хранящая как ключ уникальное сочетание {enum TokenType, enum NonterminalType} и соответствующий им номер правила, или избавиться от словаря и сразу в качестве значения использовать делегат необходимого метода-правила.Пробовал с DataTable, но ничего путного не выходит.

Comment: @VladD хотя в принципе придумал, просто использовать Dictionary<List<Enum>,int /*или Delegate*/ >

Comment: @Сергей: У нас на сайте где-то был пример парсера, сейчас найду...

Comment: @Сергей: Вот вам [парсер рекурсивного спуска](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/518922/10105) (`LL(1)`).

Comment: @VladD, спасибо! В любом случае стараюсь сам разобраться и сделать, но и костыли изобретать тоже не хочется, так что ваша помощь в плане ресурсов для меня неоценима)

Comment: @Сергей: Пожалуйста! Обращайтесь.