# Лексический анализ условного выражения

Tags: c++, алгоритм

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;
int k=0;
string substr(string s, int start, int end){
    if(start < 0 || start > end || end < 0) return "";
    else if(start == end){
        return string(1, s[start]);
    }
    else {
        string str;
        for(int i=start; i < end || i < s.length(); i++){
            str += s[i];
        }
        return str;
    }
}

bool isId(string s){
    if(s[0] >= '0' && s[0] <= '9') return false;
    for(int i=0; i<s.length(); i++){
        if(!(s[i] >= 'a' && s[i] <= 'z' || s[i] >= 'A' && s[i] <= 'Z' || s[i] >= '0' && s[i] <= '9'))
            return false;
    }
    return true;
}


bool isDigit(const string& s){
    for(int i=0; i<s.length(); i++){
        if(s[i] < '0' || s[i] > '9') return false;
    }
    return true;
}
bool isCondition(string s){
    int k=0, z=0;
    for(int i=0; i < s.length(); i++){
        if(s[i] == '!' || s[i] == '='){
            if(s[i+1] != '=') return false;
            k=i;
            z=i+1;
            break;
        }
        else if(s[i] == '<' || s[i] == '>'){
            k=z=i;
            if(s[i+1] == '=')z++;
            break;
        }
    }
    if((isId(substr(s, 0, k-1)) || isDigit(substr(s, 0, k-1))) && (isId(substr(s, k+1, s.length() - 1)) || isDigit(substr(s, k+1, s.length() - 1)))) return true;
}
bool isAriphmetic(string s){
    int k=0, z=0;
    for(int i=0; i < s.length(); i++){
        if(s[i] == '='){
            k=i;
            for(int j=i; j < s.length(); j++){
                if(s[j] == '+' || s[j] == '-' || s[j] == '*' || s[j] == '/'){
                    z=j;
                    break;
                }
            }
            break;
        }
    }
    if(z ==0 || k == 0 || s[s.length() -1] != ';') return false;
    return (isId(substr(s, 0, k-1)) && (isId(substr(s, k+1, z-1)) || isDigit(substr(s, k+1, z-1))) && (isId(substr(s, z+1, s.length()-2)) || isDigit(substr(s, z+1, s.length()-2))));
}
string get(string buffer){
    string s;
    for(int i=k; i < buffer.length(); i++){
        if(s == "" && buffer[i] == ' ') continue;
        else if(buffer[i] == ' ') {
            k++;
            break;
        }
        s += buffer[i];
        k++;
    }
    return s;
}
void searchSolve(string buffer){
    if(buffer == "if") {
        cout << "is if" << endl;
    }
    else if(buffer == "then"){
        cout << "is then" << endl;
    }
    else if(buffer == "["){
        cout << "is [" << endl;
    }
    else if(buffer == "else"){
        cout << "is else" << endl;
    }
    else if(buffer == "]"){
        cout << "is ]" << endl;
    }
    else if(buffer == "end") {
        cout << "is end" << endl;
    }
    else if(isDigit(buffer)){
        cout << "is const" << endl;
    }
    else if(buffer == "==" || buffer == "<" || buffer == ">" || buffer == ">=" || buffer == "<=" || buffer == "!="){
        cout << "is condition" << endl;
    }
    else if(buffer == "=" || buffer == "+" || buffer == "-" || buffer == "*" || buffer == "/"){
        cout << "is ariphmetic" << endl;
    }
    else if(isCondition(buffer)){
        cout << "is condition, id, const" << endl;
    }
    else if(isAriphmetic(buffer)){
        cout << "is ariphmetic ur" << endl;
    }
}

int main(){
    string s = "if a>5 then a=5+6; [ else a=5+5; ] end";
    string buff;
    while((buff = get(s)) != ""){
        cout << buff << " ";
        searchSolve(buff);
    }
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

пытался написать лексический анализ условного выражения. Можно ли так вообще писать, я разбивал слова по пробелам и сравнивал с лексемами.... Обычно же пишут по другому, у нас на лекции совсем другой код был. Оптимальный ли мой вариант вообще?

Comment: Вы уже второй с этим вопросом за последние пару часов :)

Comment: Лексический анализ условного выражения — оксюморон. Целью лексического анализа является, грубо говоря, разбиение входного текста на лексемы (токены). Собирание лексем в условное выражение — задача синтаксического анализа.

Comment: кстати, зачем вы пишете функцию `substr`? у `std::string` уже есть `substr`.

Comment: у меня были гвозди с 1 символом

Comment: Я бы посоветовал вам взять недавно вышедшее 2-е (только второе! в первом ошибок столько, что только вредит) издание Страуструпа *"Программирование. Принципы и практика с использованием C++"* и почитать. Как начинающему, оно вообще полезно, ну а конкретно для вас - там детально, в нескольких главах разбирается написание калькулятора, т.е. разбор арифметических выражений. Очень рекомендую.