# Лексический и синтаксический анализ

Tags: c++, синтаксический-анализ

Объясните пожалуйста, как в алгоритмированной форме должен выглядеть лексический и синтаксический анализ строчки : "a<5 | b>8 & 3 < 4". Насколько я понимаю лексический анализ считывает символ и переходил в дальнейшее состояние, и после каждой лексемы состояние обнуляется. А в синтаксическом тоже самое только состояния не обнуляются а следуют друг за другом.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Лексический анализ разбивает строку на последовательность лексем. Для вашего случая, например, будет что-то такое

Вход:

```
a<5 | b>8 & 3 < 4
```

Выход:

```
IDENT("a") LESS NUM_LITERAL(5) OR IDENT("b") GREATER NUM_LITERAL(8) AND
    NUM_LITERAL(8) LESS NUM_LITERAL(4)
```

Синтаксический анализ из последовательности лексем строит синтаксическое дерево.

Вход:

```
IDENT("a") LESS NUM_LITERAL(5) OR IDENT("b") GREATER NUM_LITERAL(8) AND
    NUM_LITERAL(8) LESS NUM_LITERAL(4)
```

Выход:

```
                  LOGICAL_OR
                  /        \
                 /          \
                /            \
               /             LOGICAL_AND
         COMPARISON(<)        /        \
          /    \             /          \
VAR_VALUE("a")  \         COMPARISON(>)  COMPARISON(<)
                 \        /     \           /      \
        CONST_VALUE(5)   /       \         /      CONST_VALUE(4)
                        /         \    CONST_VALUE(3)
                   VAR_VALUE("b")  \
                                CONST_VALUE(8)
```

---

Сами по себе внутренние состояния анализаторов по существу дело десятое, это подробности имплементации.

---

Конкретных алгоритмов лексического и синтаксического анализа множество, я не берусь их все описать.

Простой лексический анализатор может для входной строки получить текущую позицию, попробовать найти все возможные лексемы, и выбрать длиннейшую из них. Затем отбросить распознанный кусок строки, и повторить, пока строка не закончится. Пример такого анализатора — [в соседнем ответе](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/519399/10105).

Comment: а как из выходных лексем прийти к дереву?

Comment: @j6wj1997 например, [алгоритмом сортировочной станции](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%90%D0%BB%D0%B3%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%BC_%D1%81%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B9_%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BD%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%B8).

Comment: я так и не понял как с помощь синтаксического анализа проверить на правильность строку деревом, объясните пожалуйста с некорректным примером.

Comment: @j6wj1997: Ну, когда вы строите дерево, из неправильных строк оно просто не построится. Например, если у вас строка `3 > <`, вы начинаете строить дерево, у вас есть правило в грамматике: `сравнение ::= числовое_выражение знак числовое_выражение`, 3 подходит под `числовое_выражение`, `>` подходит под `знак`, а из `<` не получается числовое выражение.