# Регулярные выражения, поиск вложенных тегов

Tags: регулярные-выражения

Есть такая структура:

```
IF
 first text
 IF 
   second text
 ENDIF
ENDIF

IF
 thid text
ENDIF
```

Глубина вложенности - максимум один уровень, как в примере.

Как мне вытащить: а) все условия с текстом; б) весь текст отдельно?

Comment: Парсером, а не регекспами.

Comment: Уровень вложения обязательно с пробелами в начале строки?

Comment: Для данной задачи лучше использовать xpath или xsl запросы. В зависимости от языка разные библиотеки хорошо обрабатывают запросы и запросы достаточно простые, например /IF/IF/* - даст елементы на третьем уровне вложеные в /IF/IF.

Comment: Между тегами могут быть не только пробелы, но и вообще любой текст. Полагаю, что надо  использовать рекурсивные шаблоны http://php.net/manual/ru/regexp.reference.recursive.php

Comment: Для рекурсивных структур регулярки — неподходящий инструмент. Напишите лучше парсер.

Comment: @VladD очень часто в подобных вопросах вижу совет написать парсер, но никто ни разу не написал даже примерно в ответе как будет выглядеть парсер. Есть смутное подозрение, что написать парсер сложнее, чем регулярное выражение (при условии, что понимаешь регулярные выражения) :-)

Comment: @ReinRaus: Как это никто не написал? http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/518922/10105, http://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/451940/10105 Насчёт сложнее поспорил бы. Прикиньте регулярку, разбирающую текст типа [этого](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/451940/10105). И ещё  возможностью лёгкого добавления других контрольных структур, например, цикла `for`.

Comment: @VladD именно то, про что я и говорил - каждый из приведенных примеров парсеров- это куча кода, который надо понять, поддерживать, а еще (возможно) фиксить баги. Сложнее регулярки.

Comment: @ReinRaus: намного проще. Добавить цикл `for` в тот парсер — работа на пять минут, а за сколько времени вы сделаете это регуляркой? Глубина вложенности, разумеется, произвольная.

Comment: От ситуации зависит. Тут разовый случай, разворачивать дело в сторону написания парсера смысла нет никакого.

Comment: @Stanislav: А завтра глубина вложенности увеличивается, и приходится писать костыль?

Comment: @Stanislav: В любом случае, совет ReinRaus стоит слушать: он у нас здесь кажется единственный и точно самый лучший специалист по регуляркам. Я не шучу.

Comment: @VladD: разделяю справедливые опасения, но, как уже упоминал, это частный случай, да и в принципе стало интересно как это можно сделать. Вынес сюда, и спасибо RR - все мы получили +1 к опыту.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

https://regex101.com/r/kO1wD8/6

```
\bIF\b(?:(?R)|[^EI]++|[EI])*?\bENDIF\b
```

Между `IF` и `ENDIF` находятся:

- не `EI` - `[^EI]++`
- `EI`- `[EI]`
- вложенная конструкция из `IF` и `ENDIF` - `(?R)`

Квантификатор к альтернативе минимальный, потому что иначе будет захвачен весь текст целиком, так как `[^EI]++|[EI]` соответствует любому символу.

Comment: По ссылке: No match groups were extracted. Не работает.

Comment: Regex101 в блоке справа показывает только захватывающие группы, которых нет в регулярном выражении, потому что не нужны. Сверху зеленым написано «2 матч» и в самом тексте эти совпадения выделены другим цветом.

Comment: Хорошо, получается он находит только первый уровень, чтобы найти второй пробежимся разок по тексту найденного?

Comment: Да. Иначе невозможно. Ведь ищется текст, который соответствует любому уровню вложенности.

Comment: Аааа. Понял, наконец. А я почему-то пытался найти всё это время решение, что бы вытащить вложенные тоже, видать выспаться надо. Спасибо за помощь.