# Что происходит в компиляторе?

Tags: java, компиляция

> Исходный текст программ на Java состоит из **совокупности пробелов,
>   идентификаторов, литералов, комментариев, операторов, разделителей и ключевых
>   слов.**

Что происходит в компиляторе с каждым из выделенных понятий? Что-то отсеивается или как-то видоизменяется?

Comment: [Книгу Дракона](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9A%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%BF%D0%B8%D0%BB%D1%8F%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%8B:_%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%BF%D1%8B,_%D1%82%D0%B5%D1%85%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%B8%D0%B8_%D0%B8_%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D1%83%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D1%8B) читали?

Comment: @VladD: Нет, не читал, спасибо, гляну обязательно

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Обычная практика при написании компилятора — разделение его на части. Традиционно, первая часть — лексический анализ, деление исходного текста на лексемы. Это означает, что код читается как последовательность символов, и представляется в виде последовательности *токенов*.

Токен состоит из типа токена и значения (упакованы в один класс).

При этом обычно пробелы (не являющиеся частью символьных/строковых литералов) отбрасываются, идентификаторы превращаются в токен типа «Идентификатор» со значением, равным строке с именем идентификатора. Литералы также превращаются в токены. Комментарии стадию лексического анализа обычно не проходят и просто отбрасываются. Разделители, наподобие скобок и знаков препинания, образуют каждый собственный тип токена. Ну и для ключевых слов тоже обычно выделяют по отдельному типу токена.

Пример:

Исходный текст

```
public class Example { // пример
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(/* этот текст будет напечатан*/"hello world");
    }
}
```

производит такую последовательность лексических токенов:

```
[public-keyword] [class-keyword] [ident "Example"] [separator-left-brace] [public-keyword]
[static-keyword] [void-keyword] [ident "main"] [separator-left-paren] [ident "String"]
[separator-left-brack] [separator-right-brack] [ident "args"] [separator-right-paren]
[separator-left-brace] [ident "System"] [separator-dot] [ident "out"] [separator-dot]
[ident "println"] [separator-left-paren] [string-literal "hello world"]
[separator-right-paren] [separator-semicolon] [separator-right-brace] [separator-right-brace]
```

Дальнейшие фазы компиляции разобьют это на определения классов, функций, и операции, проверят соответствие имён, привяжут имена к объектам, проверят на осмысленность, проведут оптимизацию и скомпилируют в байт-код.

Лексический анализ — самая простая фаза компиляции.

---

Да, теоретически можно (а [иногда и приходится](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_lexer_hack)) строить компиляторы, в которых лексический анализ по сути совмещён с последующими фазами компиляции. В принципе, ничто не заставляет выделять авторов компилятора отдельную фазу лексического анализа, но всё же это общепринятая практика.

Comment: `@VladD: очень интересный ответ, благодарю вас

Comment: @TimurVI: Пожалуйста! Рад, если окажется полезным.

Comment: @TimurVI: [Вот здесь](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/518922/10105) есть простой пример лексического анализатора (класс `tokenizer`).

Comment: @TimurVI, а тут сразу предлагают [Давайте создадим компилятор!](http://www.kulichki.com/kit/crenshaw/crenshaw.html)